# Virus scanner as a service

Tags: cloud-service, antivirus

I am looking for a commercial-grade cloud antivirus solution with an API that can be programmatically called to scan user-uploaded files.

It should

- Use a known scanning engine (or multiple)
- Be GDPR compliant

Comment: Like VirusTotal? It offers an API to upload/check, with implementations for multiple languages (I wrote one for PHP), and has ~60 engines as backends (including several well-known). Maybe you could [edit] your question and include what programming languages would be acceptable?

Comment: The programming language should not matter if they have a REST API. Is VirusTotal GDPR compliant?

Comment: AFAIR they have a REST API (didn't look into my code for a while). No idea concerning GDPR compliance, I didn't check recently. [Their privacy policy](https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002168385-Privacy-Policy) doesn't even mention the term GDPR, nor do their TOS. Considering it belongs to Google, I'm not that sure… But then, what PII do you send them? All they get is the file to scan and your IP, right? Ah OK, plus the data needed to obtain the API key…

Comment: Yes, but the file might contain sensitive user data. I asked them about GDPR compliance and the problem is (and this is stated in their TOS) that user files will be shared among their virus scanning peers. So that pretty much rules them out.

Comment: Ah, in that case yes. Maybe you could [edit] that fact into your question so it's more clear in which context your GDPR compliance requirement stands? Might even ring a bell with some reader.